# How to send 2 numbers from Angular, add them with Node.js and display the result back in Angular? (Only those 2... no databases, no libraries)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I am new to Angular and Node.js. I know this must be very simple but I am having a hard time finding the answer with some sample code just by searching it in google (using Angular with Node.js) and find this solution being done with only Angular or only Node.js. I am trying to understand how Angular and Node.js work together. In YouTube I find tutorials of making a MEAN app (which ends up doing a CRUD with MongoDB), but in my case I don't want to use a database just plain Angular with Node.js.

To make things simple, I want 2 textboxes with a button in Angular that sends the 2 numbers to Node.js and adds them in Node.js. Then I want the answer to be sent back from Node.js to Angular and be displayed in another textbox in Angular.

How would I achieve this? Could I be provided with some code to understand? (I am trying to do something totally different from what I am asking, but it will help me to understand and make sense of how the Angular works with Node.js)

Comment: You should look into the HTTPClient for Angular and how to build a NodeJS API backend. I’d recommend buying a tutorial and working through it methodically. This is a little bigger than one SO post imo.

Comment: i'm writing an example for you. wait some minutes!

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: @Fartab Yes, I am looking into it right now. I appreciate the help :) . If I have any questions ill let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we write a simple http server using node:

```
const http  = require('http');

const httpServer = http.createServer(requestHandler);
httpServer.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Node.JS server is listening on port 3000')
});

function requestHandler(request, response){
  console.log(`Request came: ${request.url}`);
  if(request.url.startsWith('/add/')){
      try{
          let parts = request.url.substring(5).split('/')
          let result = Number(parts[0]) + Number(parts[1])
          response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'});
          response.write(result.toString());
          response.end();
          console.log(`Response: 200 ${request.url}`);
          return;
      }catch(e){
          console.log(e);
      }
  }
  response.writeHead(400);
  response.write(`bad request '${request.url}' is not valid. example url: /add/5/7`);
  response.end();
  console.log("Response: 404 ${request.url}");
}
```

Save above code as `server.js` and run it using `node server.js`

Then create an angular project using `ng new node-ng-test`

Edit `app.component.html` like this:

```
<input type="number" #firstNumber>
<input type="number" #secondNumber>
<button (click)="callAddApi(firstNumber.value, secondNumber.value)">Add</button>

<p *ngIf="result"> {{firstNumber.value}} + {{secondNumber.value}} = {{result}}</p>
```

Also change `app.component.ts` as this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  result = undefined;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  callAddApi(firstNumber, secondsNumber) {
    this.http.get<any>(`http://localhost:3000/add/${firstNumber}/${secondsNumber}`)
      .subscribe(r => this.result = r, e => console.log(e));
  }
}
```

Don't forget to import `HttpClientModule` in `app.module.ts`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Finally, run angular app using `ng serve --open` and try it!

Comment: It worked great! Im still figuring out how everything works but it is a nice example.

Comment: I’m open to describe it, feel free to ask more